# Accessing global variables from within a thread

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I have python file with httpHandler class.
I use it with ThreadingMixIn as follows:

```
from SocketServer import ThreadingMixIn
from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
Successful_Attempts = 0
Failed_Attempts = 0

class httpHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_POST(self):
        .....


class ThreadingHTTPServer(ThreadingMixIn, HTTPServer):
    pass
```

and later on I initiate it as follows:

```
server = ThreadingHTTPServer(('localhost', PORT_NUMBER), httpHandler)
        print 'Started httpserver on port ' , PORT_NUMBER
```

So as I understand, the httpHandler class, once a connection is made, is already in a different thread.
I want to keep track on my threads, some sort of statistics handling.
However I cant access my variables.
Also, I need to lock them, so that they'll represent real values, not something undefined correctly

Comment: A very low-level idea would be creating a global list and store variables in it. But you have to watch out not to write the same list at the same time with two different threads (as you said a lock needs to be provided) but if you just got 2 threads (main and some working one) you could just read with main and just write with the working one without trouble (and the need of a lock) - just a comment becaus there might be a better way

Comment: @Martin, from what I've seen Queues seem to be the defacto way for sharing information between threads in python.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a thread safe singleton for that.

**Edit:** johnthexiii suggested that I should post a simple example, so here it is. It's not exactly a singleton, but mimics one, class variables are global per application, so instead instantiating a singleton class we're working directly with the class, calling its class methods.

```
from threading import Lock


class ThreadSafeGlobalDataContainer:
    __container = {}
    __lock = Lock()

    @classmethod
    def set(cls, name, value):
        with cls.__lock:
            cls.__container[name] = value

    @classmethod
    def get(cls, name):
        with cls.__lock:
            return cls.__container[name]


#in some thread
ThreadSafeGlobalDataContainer.set('someName', 'someValue')

#somewhere else
print(ThreadSafeGlobalDataContainer.get('someName'))
```

Comment: Could you post a simple example of that?

Comment: @johnthexiii here it is